# goodness-of-fit test for categorical data with small expected frequencies

Tags: statistics

I have a categorical data set with 8 categories and I want to test my data against a theoretical "ideal" distribution.  Usually I think a chi square test does this just fine; however, some of my theoretical probabilities are small and therefore my theoretical distribution says that 3 of my 8 categories have an expected frequency smaller than 5.  I've been told that such small expected frequencies mean that chi square is not appropriate.  So my question is: when we have some categories with small expected frequencies, what kind of goodness-of-fit test is appropriate?  I've been googling around and getting conflicting answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to think about your objectives as well as the
appropriateness of a chi-squared test.

Suppose you roll a die 18 times to get an idea whether
it is fair. If it is biased with probabilities $(2,2,3,3,4,4)/18$ of the respective faces, you have two issues to deal with: (a) some of the faces may have counts below five, (b) even if the test runs OK, it does not have much power to reject the null hypothesis that all faces are equally likely.

(a)

```
set.seed(405)
pr = c(2,2,3,3,4,4)/18
TAB = tabulate(sample(1:6, 18, rep=T, p = pr))
TAB
[1] 2 1 3 4 6 2
chisq.test(TAB)

        Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  TAB
X-squared = 5.3333, df = 5, p-value = 0.3766

Warning message:
In chisq.test(TAB) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

The `given probabilities` are all equal, unless otherwise specified. The expected count in each of the six cells
is $3,$ which generates a warning message.

There is a 'cure' for moderately low cell counts. The implementation of `chisq.test` in R allows
you to simulate a reasonably accurate P-value, which
finds no significant difference from fairness.

```
chisq.test(TAB, sim=T)

    Chi-squared test for given probabilities 
    with simulated p-value 
    (based on 2000 replicates)

data:  TAB
X-squared = 5.3333, df = NA, p-value = 0.4138
```

(b) However, there is ***no cure*** for the low power of the test with only 18 rolls of the die. With so few few rolls of this die, the probability of detecting that the die is biased is disappointingly small.

Even with 60 rolls of the die (and consequently very rare low cell counts), the power of the chi-squared test is only about 31%, as illustrated by the simulation below.

```
set.seed(2021)
pr = c(2,2,3,3,4,4)/18
m = 10^5;  pv = numeric(m)
for(i in 1:m) {
  TAB = tabulate(sample(1:6, 60, rep=T, p=pr))
  pv[i] = chisq.test(TAB)$p.val
  }
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.31181
```

*Note:* With 600 rolls of the die, you would almost surely
detect the bias; power above 99% (simulation not shown).

---

*Addendum:* Using data from your Comment, with the simulated option
to accommodate small counts.

```
x= c(16, 15, 6, 9, 7, 6, 4, 5)
a=c(19.2, 13.3, 8.8, 8.2, 6.7, 4.7, 3.9, 3.2)
chisq.test(x, p=a/sum(a), sim=T)

        Chi-squared test for given probabilities 
        with simulated p-value (based on 2000 replicates)
data:  x
X-squared = 3.1077, df = NA, p-value = 0.8786
```

Here `given probabilities` are provided by re-scaling your
"ideal" distribution to sum to $1.$ The null hypothesis that
data `x` fit your ideal distribution is not rejected. (Of course, as always,
with very much more data you might reject, but if agreement seems
reasonable to you based on what you know about the subject matter,
then this outcome is likely OK.)

If you do `chisq.test` without simulation, then you get P-value 0.8749,
which is actually not much different, but does generate a warning message because
of the 'low' counts.

```
X-squared = 3.1077, df = 7, p-value = 0.8749
```

In a formal report, you might give the P-value as 0.8749, with
a note saying that simulation confirms it is nearly correct. Alternatively, show simulated
results from R (as earlier), mentioning R's simulation capability in a note.

[The 'rule', triggering the warning message, is that all expected counts must be
smaller than 5. This rule is considered to be too 'fussy' by some, who say it's
OK to have a 'few' counts as low as 3, provided 'most' exceed 5. Of course,
all such rules are arbitrary. Because we did it with and without simulation,
we ***know*** the P-value from the chi-squared distribution isn't far off.]

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  My sample size is 68, close to your value of 60 which you warn about.  Given my (unavoidable) small sample size, is there an appropriate test to use?  I read online about "exact" tests like Fisher or multinomial that could be used when there are low expected frequencies, but I couldn't quite tell if those were appropriate in my context.

Comment: Depending on how much your 8 categories might differ, 60 could be enough. If you could say more about your 'ideal distribution' and  an alternative distribution that you would want to detect, then it would be easier to say what sample size is needed.

Comment: My ideal distribution is something like [19.2, 13.3, 8.8, 8.2, 6.7, 4.7, 3.9, 3.2] and an observed distribution is something like [16, 15, 6, 9, 7, 6, 4, 5].  Chi square seems like a natural way to test the fit of the second to the first, but I've been told that this is problematic because of the three expected frequencies that are less than 5.

Comment: Just now saw your Comment, and posted an addendum to my Answer using that information.

Comment: Thank you for the help